# Как подогнать размер ImageView к размеру картинки

Tags: java, android, изображения, view

Создала вот такой ImageView:

```
    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/homeImage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/homescreen_200px"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:background="@color/red"

    />
```

Background специально задала, потому что не могла понять, почему у меня следующий элемент нарисован так низко. Оказалось, что ImageView торчит вниз где-то на 30 пикселей ниже картинки. Не пойму в чем может быть дело? Как мне убрать это поле? Вроде wrap_content для высоты должен это обеспечивать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить к `ImageView` атрибут `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`

Comment: работает, спасибо